# How to predict longer sentences using Keras OCR recognizer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, ocr

I've followed [this](https://keras-ocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fine_tuning_recognizer.html) tutorial for fine tuning a recognizer with your own dataset. The problem is, I'm using my own custom alphabet for a model, and when I try assigning an alphabet I run into an error:

> AssertionError: A sentence is longer than this model can predict

The custom alphabet I'm using consists of these characters:

> [' ', '!', '"', '#', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', '=', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', '
> Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'Ü', 'ä', 'é', 'α', '★', '☆']

And I declare the recognizer like this:

```
import keras_ocr
...
recognizer = keras_ocr.recognition.Recognizer(alphabet=alphabet)
recognizer.compile()
```

I've looked into the source code and seen that the error comes from here:

`assert all(len(sentence) <= max_string_length for sentence in sentences), "A sentence is longer than this model can predict."`

max_string_length is defined here:

`max_string_length = self.training_model.input_shape[1][1]`

However, it seems that input_shape is looking for the shape of the images that the OCR model will be scanning for text. How can I create my recognizer with an input shape that will allow for longer sentence matching? The longest sentence I'm currently trying to match is 54 characters.